# Integration of mail, wiki and calendar programs

Tags: calendar, gmail, note-taking, wiki

The issue is related to the organization of my work through Gmail and other Google tools. At the moment I use:

- Gmail for emails (local copy of all emails with my email client through IMAP)
- Calendar to store events, appointments, meetings dates etc. which is great because it is connected to Gmail, I can send reminders and simply use emails to create new events
- Documents (on my HD and partially on gDrive)

Wonderful! What do I miss, then?

One feature that I really miss, and that only Evernote is able to fulfill, is to take note of my day-by-day work. I need basically a note-taking software. For this, Evernote is great.

But it would be even greater if I was able to do everything from one single integrated environment. I understand that for files that would be a bit difficult, so what I'm searching now is some software or some Gmail plugin which allow me to take notes and search among notes.

Unfortunately the level of integration of Evernote into Gmail is very low.

Also, I considered using emails with notes, which might be an option, but the problem is that emails cannot be edited.

The best choice to me, to let you understand which is my 'dream', is to have a sort of wiki inside of Gmail. Something like a folder with subfolders where I can organize all my notes, attach files and pictures.

Maybe something like an "Evernote" folder into Gmail.

It would also work for me to have a software (running under Mac OS X) with all these features together.

Does something like this exist?

Can I achieve it by means of additional components to Gmail, Mac OS X mail, or other software (Thunderbird)?

Comment: I use cherrytree (on linux,but it should be available for windows too) for note taking, code storage, etc. However, it lacks mail an calendar functionality. Hope that someone will get interested in such project.